# unable to echo option values retrieved from backend using php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am unable to echo the value of retrieved data

Here is my code:

```
   <html>
   <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
        echo "<select class=\"chapter\">";
        echo "<option value=\"\">Select Chapter</option>" ?>
    //  $sql="select 'ChapterName' from 'chapter'";
        $sql = "SELECT `ChapterName` FROM `chapter`";
        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error($connection));              
        }  
        $result=mysql_query($sql);     
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $option=$row['ChapterName'];
                echo '<option value=\"\">$row[\'ChapterName\']</option>' ?>     
                echo "<script>alert(".$option.")</script>";
        }

              ?>
              </select><br/><br/><html>
```

it gives the following output ::

```
   $row[\'ChapterName\']
```

in the drop down menu.....

Comment: why you want echo "<script>alert(".$option.")</script>"; in the code?

Comment: mysql* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<html>
   <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
        echo "<select class=\"chapter\">";
        echo "<option value=\"\">Select Chapter</option>";
        $sql = "SELECT `ChapterName` FROM `chapter`";
        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error($connection));              
        }  
        $result=mysql_query($sql);     
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<option value=''>".$row['ChapterName']."</option>";     
        }

    ?>
        </select><br/><br/>
<html>
```

Comment: I know this is sort of dumb question, but when do we use this ' and when do we use this " ?

Comment: @Rashmi: Please check this link about single and double quotes. http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variable values:

```
$foo = 'bar';

echo '$foo'; // output: $, f, o, o
echo "$foo"; // output: b, a, r
```

So:

```
echo '<option value=\"\">$row[\'ChapterName\']</option>' ?>
```

should be

```
echo "<option value=\"\">$row[ChapterName]</option>" ?>     
     ^---    note the change in quotes      -------^
```

Comment: I believe your answer will work, but `ChapterName` will only be treated as a string because it is not defined as a constant and would produce warnings if they were enabled. I think it should be quoted

Comment: @andrew: no. array keys cannot be quoted in double-quoted strings, UNLESS you use the `{}` notation. bad: `echo "$foo['bar']"`. ok: `echo "$foo[bar]"` ok: `echo "{$foo['bar']}"`

Comment: then you didn't change `'` quotes to `"`.

Comment: @mark, I just the code. Here is the output with warnings enabled `Notice: Use of undefined constant ChapterName - assumed 'ChapterName'`

Comment: then something's screwy with your code. somehow the $row part is being seen as being OUTSIDE of the string.

Comment: @mark. scratch that, you're right I'm wrong, i learned something new

Comment: @MarcB i tried this too...         echo "<option value=\"\">$row['ChapterName']</option>" ?>

Comment: @user3649254 you have more php code after that line, remove the closing `?>`

Comment: @andrew: no worries. here's another fun one: multi-dimensional arrays in `"`-quoted strings MUST use `{}` notation. `echo "$foo[bar][baz]"` is actually parsed/executed as `echo $foo['bar'] . "[baz]"` (but produces `Array[baz]`), because the parser isn't "greedy" with the array keys.

Comment: @MarcB then how to fix it so that it is not seen as OUTSIDE of the string?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you need:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('cannot connect'); 
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die('cannot select DB');
?>

    <select class="chapter">
    <option value="">Select Chapter</option>
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT `ChapterName` FROM `chapter`';
    $sql = mysql_query($sql); //added this

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error($connection));              
    }  

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<option value="">'.$row['ChapterName'].'</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
```

please let me know if you have any errors so I can fix them